# Jupyter notebook make output cell higher

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am running a  jupyter notebook and this is a map i plotted:

[image: map]

Is there any way to make the output cell `Out [49]` higher? I only found a way to make it wider, which is already implemented in my notebook.

Comment: Post the code as text please

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t, I thought there would be just a magical command from Jupiter to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the figure size bigger, the cell size will resize automatically

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
```